# How to delete a file from an Android application

Tags: android

How can I delete a file from an Android application? Can I do it the same way I would for deleting a file in Java?

Answer (score 3):

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

and set this permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Answer (score 2):

The [Android Developer Homepage](http://developer.android.com/index.html) has a really good Dev Guide section.

Answer to your question:
Files can be deleted using: `File.delete()` method. (I found that by searching for "file delete" on the page above!)

But of course, there's much more to that: you need to understand how Android stores files and which files your application is allowed to modify! (basically only its own files, all the others are not accessible)

Answer (score 1):

```
    File file = new File(path);
    return file.delete();
```