# How to delete files on android using flutter "File Class"?

Tags: android, file, flutter

I am making a flutter app and i want to allow the user to be able to delete the files from sd card or phone storage using my app.
code used

```
File f = new File.fromUri(Uri.file(song.uri));
f.delete();
```

in `File Class` there are two functions `delete()` and `deleteSync()` i tried using both the functions but there is error coming something related to `permission denied` . How can i delete the file then??

Error while deleting file --

```
E/flutter (16195): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (16195): FileSystemException: Cannot delete file,
path = '/storage/2748-0816/Music/AUD-20180613-WA0006.mp3' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
E/flutter (16195): #0      _File._delete.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:295:9)
E/flutter (16195): #1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1381:54)
E/flutter (16195): #2      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
E/flutter (16195): #3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:633:45)
E/flutter (16195): #4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:662:32)
E/flutter (16195): #5      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:477:5)
E/flutter (16195): #6      Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous
closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:507:7)
E/flutter (16195): #7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (16195): #8      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

My android xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: Obviously the app doesn't have permission to delete this file. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270927/how-to-delete-a-file-from-an-android-application. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files might also provide some insight.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i already have that added in my xml file i'll update the question..

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot even the answers on that page are not ticked . and yes that isn't working coz i have already done that .

Comment: I think you need to ask for write permission at runtime, check the official docs https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-check You may need to do some changes in order to do it in Flutter

Comment: i got it have to try something to get permission at runtime in flutter @AlbertoMéndez

Comment: Yeah!!, I am new with Flutter so I can't recommend you a way to do it, sorry. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have included the relevant permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Add this -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Flutter stuff --->
</manifest>
```

However, maybe you are run your application on API above 6.0 devices. Try this next:

```
registrar.activity().requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

Comment: That will not work for files. It is also a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17143578/6509751

Comment: I'm editing my answer. That's copy paste mistake.

Comment: Plz, read the comment above. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Ok fine! Somebody has hands faster than brain.

Comment: @AmanMalhotra I spent 4 points to help you. Hope that help. If not, let me know. I will update my answer more detail.

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm sorry man my net stopped and i didnt see you comment before commenting .

Comment: Don't worry! I respected mr. creativecreatorormaybenot's actions but not the next guy who vote me down without any commented.